# How do go into a directory without being given its full path in python 2?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to go into a folder and call a python 2 script, but I cannot get any answer to go into a folder without using its full path. As example in DOS I would normally type this:

```
C:\unknownpath\> cd otherpath
C:\unknownpath\otherpath\>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
os.chdir('otherpath')
```

This at least matches your DOS example, and will change your working directory to `otherpath` relative to the directory the command is run from. For example if you are in `/home/myusername/`, then this will take you to `/home/myusername/otherpath/`. You can also use `.` for the current directory or `..` to move back one directory. So if you are in `/home/myusername/Desktop/`, `os.chdir('..')` would change the working directory to `/home/myusername/` and `os.chdir('../Documents/` would change you to `/home/myusername/Documents/`, etc.

Forgive my use of Unix-style paths, but you should be able to easily translate these commands to Windows paths if that is the platform you are on. I don't want to attempt to use Windows paths in my examples because I won't be able to test their efficacy.

Answer (score 0):

`os.chdir` works on relative path.

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\sba001\\PycharmProjects'
>>> os.listdir('.')
['untitled', 'untitled1', 'untitled2', 'untitled3', 'untitled4', 'untitled5']
>>> os.chdir('untitled')
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\sba001\\PycharmProjects\\untitled'
```